# Using camera when launching a website as a mobile app using PhoneGap/Apache Cordova

Tags: android, html, apache, cordova

I got a question! The thing is that I'm building a PhoneGap/Apache Cordova app. The only thing that it does is to launch a website (I need to do it this way because it's the only way to connect to a local database, so...).

If you go directly to the website from Chrome or any other browser on a mobile device, and choose to upload a photo, an option will pop up allowing you to use the camera to take the picture. In addition to that you can also upload pictures from your album.

The problem comes when you open the app from an Android device. The App goes directly to the websit and it works just fine, but when you choose the option to upload a photo the camera option is gone. I have tried several ways and the camera option won't appear.

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

This is the tag I use to upload a photo and as I said it works on the website, but it doesn't work in the app.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: have you add this? (in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira yeah! I added the lines you told me but nothing changed. Anyway, thanks for your help!